# How to pass arguments from grunt to node.js app using grunt-express-server

Tags: grunt-express

I met an issue where I need to start my express server with arguments using grunt-express-server. How could I do that?

I tried to use the option "args" but it seems it doesn't work for me. Here are some simple codes for this issue.

In my Gruntfile.js, I just did this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('proxy.json'),
  express: {
    dev: {
      options: {
        script: 'testServer.js',
        background: false,
        args: ['test.json'], // I assume it may run "node testServer.js test.json"
      }
    }
})
```

And in my testServer.js file, I just want to print out the arguments:

```
var m = require('./startServer.js');
process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
    console.log(array);
});
m.start();
```

However, everytime when I run "grunt express:dev", the server could be started, however, it always prints out

```
 [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/grunt', 'express:dev' ]
```

instead of something like

```
 [ 'node', 'testServer.js', 'test.json' ]
```

Do you have any idea how I could solve this issue?